# File Storage randomly, but frequently, giving 403 error. How do I configure for more performance in the portal?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are developing an application that will download about 10 files from Azure File Storage, one after the other. We are using the Azure File Storage Client library in a c# application. On one test machine, I will randomly get an HTTP 403 error. Sometimes this happens on the first file, sometimes on a subsequent file, and sometimes never.

On another machine, with the same code, I get the 403 all the time. I'm guessing that it's a performance issue on the Azure side. It's unlikely a real "authorization" issue, as the access key does not change, and I'm getting this issue with just one machine at a time running.

Is there some way I can configure Azure File Storage in the portal to be more performant?

Comment: Are you accessing File Storage from a VM in the same region as the storage account? Different region? From an on-premises server? I can imagine there could be networking issues when going outside of the region.

Comment: David,
No. We have remote device(s) in the field that are situated in Dr.s offices. They are custom machines running Windows 7. I'm doing testing in our development center. One machine is able to connect and download 6 or 7 files in succession with no problem. Another machine (same software, same storage connection string, same physical office as me), consistently fails with a 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't like my solution, it appears to be working.

Before each download is started, I have my thread sleep for 1 second. Since implementing this, my issues have disappeared....

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into following: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-troubleshoot-file-connection-problems#errorhold

"Host is down" error on existing file shares, or the shell hangs when you run list commands on the mount point
Cause
This error occurs on the Linux client when the client has been idle for an extended period of time. When this error occurs, the client disconnects, and the client connection times out.

Solution
This issue is now fixed in the Linux kernel as part of change set, pending backport into Linux distribution.

To works around this issue, sustain the connection and avoid getting into an idle state, keep a file in the Azure File share that you write to periodically. This has to be a write operation, such as rewriting the created/modified date on the file. Otherwise, you might get cached results, and your operation might not trigger the connection.

Comment: Thanks, but does not apply. These are windows workstations (as stated in the original post). We're not trying to mount as file shares. We are using the Azure File Storage Client library. Error 403 is an HTTP authorization error.